# Python: Print a list in reverse using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to figure out how to print out a list in reverse order using recursion.
This is how I reversed a list:

```
def reverse_list(xs):
    if xs == []:
         return xs
    else:
        new_list = (print_reverse (xs[1:])) + [xs[0]]
        return new_list
```

and this is how I printed a list in order:

```
def print_in_order(l, i = 0):
    if i < len(l):
        print (l[i])
        print_in_order(l, i + 1)
```

I tried just printing out from the new list inside the function like this:

```
def print_reverse(xs):
    if xs == []:
        return xs
    else:
        new_list = (print_reverse (xs[1:])) + [xs[0]]
    for number in new_list: 
        print (number)
```

But it raises an error. How do you combine the two processes?

Comment: Why don't just modify `print_in_order`? start from `len(l) - 1` and  check `if i >= 0`?

Comment: What do you mean start from len(1) -1?

Comment: `print_in_order` starts from `i = 0` i.e. from the beginning of the string, `print_in_reverse` should start from `i = len(l) - 1` - from the last character of the string. Side note: Do not use `l` when it's easy to mix it with `1`

Comment: I tried adding i = len(l)-1 to the 2nd parameter but it raises an error.

Comment: why don't use any byway e.g. i = None, and then, in the function's body check if `i = None` assign it to `len(l) - 1`?

Comment: I am very new to recursion. The print_in_order function makes sense to me but the reverse method does not at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that (`print_in_order` adaptation):

```
# print l in reverse order, starting from i
# note, that we're allowed not to specify i
def print_in_reverse(l, i = None):
    # if i is not specified    
    if (i is None):
        i = len(l) - 1 

    # we're printing in reverse: 
    # we have to check for beginning of the string instead of ending
    # that's why check for 0 
    if (i >= 0):
        print (l[i])
        print_in_reverse(l, i - 1) # reverse direction: i - 1 instead of i + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to swap two lines:

```
def print_in_reverse(lst, i=0):
    if i < len(lst):
        print_in_reverse(lst, i + 1)  # Do the recursive call before you
        print (lst[i])              # print instead of after
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest way to do this, it's using slicing in this way:

```
>>> example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> example[::-1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

..and if you want to print them, just do this:

```
>>> for number in example:
...     print(number)
...     
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

EDITED:

```
>>> example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> def recursive(list, counter=0):
...     if len(list) > counter:
...         print(list[counter])
...         recursive(list, counter+1)
...     return
... 

>>> recursive(example[::-1])
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: It's a homework exercise that requires you to use recursion and put it in a defined function form.

Comment: How can I modify my print_in_order function to print in reversed order?

Comment: You can simply pass to the print_in_order method the sliced reversed list, and iterate on it recursively to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just print it in reverse order and you don't want to change original list you can just modify `print_in_order()` like this:

```
#second parameter is length of list
def print_in_reversed(l, i): 
    if i > 0:
        print (l[i-1])
        print_in_order(l, i - 1)
```

And you will call it with this example

```
example = [1,2,3,4,5]    
print_in_order(example, len(example))
```